# Android Navigation Drawer new style

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

In this type of Navigation Drawer, when you swipe from the left edge of the screen, current screen moves to right side while resizing and the Navigation Drawer become visible by a transparency transition effect while its resizing too. And also the Navigation Drawer shows up from behind of the current activity.

Like this one, my "Music" application:

[image: Navigation Drawer Sample in Music Application]

So, how can I achieve this kind of Navigation Drawer? Is there any library, tutorial or...?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closet library I found is [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu).

An example on Google Play:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.slidingmenu.example&hl=en

Answer (score 1):

its not navigation drawer (navigation drawer always comes from the top of screen).

you can use sliding layout.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout.html

Comment: Okay, thanks for the point. You know any library for implementing what I want?